# Using $\int_{0}^{1} x^n dx =\frac{1}{n+1}$ find the sums of the series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> $$1-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n-2}+\cdots$$

Sorry for being silly. I thought this
$\frac{1}{3n-2}=\frac{1}{n+1}$
so  if $n=3/2$.

Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }  (-1)^{n+1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}n} dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n-2}$$

But, I don't know if they are asking me this and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please put your math expressions between two `$` signs to render them nicely.

Comment: @cosmo5 I owe you one!

Comment: is $n$ finite or infinite?, like the series in block quote..?

Comment: What has your question to do with `uniform-convergence`?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos clickbait I guess. Sorry but  this is in my book :c

Comment: @Buraian does not say :c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transform
$$\frac{1}{3n-2} = \int_0^1 x^{3n-3} \mathrm d x$$
and
$$(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{3n-3}$$
Thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n-2} =
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \int_0^1 x^{3n-3} \mathrm d x =
\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} x^{3n-3} \mathrm d x =$$
$$=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^{3n-3} \mathrm d x = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3}\mathrm d x$$
note that we can swap sum and integral because the geometric series is uniformly convergent on compact sets inside $(-1; 1)$.

Now, you have to compute this integral, which is not that easy.
WA says it evaluates $$\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt 3} + \frac{\log 2}{3} \approx 0.835$$

Comment: Bro <3 You're an angel? I am checking it

Comment: in $\frac{1}{3n-2} = \int_0^1 x^{3n-1} \mathrm d x$ is $x^{3n-3}$?

Comment: This result does not check.  We have an alternating series with terms of mokotonicallu decreasing absolute values, so the sim should oie between the first partial sum $1.00$ and the second partial suk $0.75$.  The proposed value of $(\log 2)/3$ is way below this range

Comment: @davidhernandez Oh you are correct. I made a silly mistake. Now I have corrected.

Comment: Use $\frac{3}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2-x}{1-x+x^2}$.